# Android Widget with ListView displaying Loading views only

Tags: android, android-listview, android-appwidget, remoteview

I am trying to implement an **Android App Widget with a ListView**. I started by following the Google documentation but I got stuck with a **list of loading views being displayed** instead of the normal list items. Does anybody have experiences with list views in widgets?

The code is the same as in the [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections). I use a ListView instead of StackView and as data source I use a database (which isn´t the problem, data is obtained correctly - I have tried that by returning a normal list item view with correct data instead of the default loading view)

Searching the internet didn´t help me... I also tried out this [tutorial](http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/android-app-widget-with-listview/) but it did not work either.
I hope anybody can help me, thanks in advance!

### Code

**WidgetProvider.java**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventWidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            rv.setRemoteAdapter(android.R.id.list, intent);
            rv.setEmptyView(android.R.id.list, R.id.tvEmptyList);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
        }

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

**WidgetService.java**

```
public class EventWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

         return new EventsWidgetListProvider(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
}
```

**WidgetListProvider**

```
public class EventsWidgetListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

    private List<> _entities = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context _context;
//  private int _appWidgetId;

    public EventsWidgetListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {

        _context = context;
//      _appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() { }

    private void refreshEntities() {

        // Request data from database
        _entities = RequestResult;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {

        final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(_context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);

        // Set data to remoteViews [remoteViews.setTextViewText(), remoteViews.setImageViewResource()]

        return remoteViews;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return _entities.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {

        refreshEntities();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() { }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {

        return new RemoteViews(_context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_loading);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't really help without seeing your code

Comment: As I already said, the code is nearly the same as in the Google docs but I have updated the question. Would be very nice if you could give me some advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `getViewTypeCount` returns `0`. Per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount()):

> If the adapter always returns the same type of View for all items, this method should return 1.

By returning `0`, you're telling the system that you have no view types to show.

Answer (score 0):

Just if you still cannot solve the problem: in my case I was using androidx type widgets in my listview item layout, for example, androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView. Changed to TextView and this fixed the issue.